# approaching the border

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ $(U\neq \mathbb{R}^m)$  open and connected. Given $b \in \partial{U}$ there is some way $\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with finite length such that $\varphi(t) \in U$ for all $0\leq t<1$ and $\varphi(1)=b$ ?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is false. Let $U=(0,1)\times(0,1)\setminus(\bigcup_{n\geq 2}\{1/n\}\times [1/2,1])$ in $\mathbb R^2$. The point $(0,1)$ is in the boundary but cannot be reached by an arc. Every sufficiently small neighborhood in $U$ of this corner point consists of infinitely many connected components, none of which has $(0,1)$ as a boundary point.

Comment: but $U$ is open y connected then is connected for arc.

Comment: @Tirifilo: every point in $U$ is connected to every point in $U$ by an arc. But that doesn't mean you can reach every boundary point by an arc, as my example shows.

Comment: certain, thank you very much!!